# ToLower () not working for Mocked repositories

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, repository

This is the situation :

In my test I use a mocked CountryRrespositoryStub :

```
_countryRepositoryStub.Setup(s => s.GetAsync(x => x.Code == "BE"))
            .ReturnsAsync(DB_COUNTRY_BELGIUM);
```

That should return this :

```
private static readonly Country DB_COUNTRY_BELGIUM = new Country
{
    Id = 1,
    Code = "BE",
    Name = "Belgium"
};
```

This is the method that is called :

```
private async Task<int> GetCountryIdAsync(string countryCode)
{ 
    var result = await _countryRepository.GetAsync(x => x.Code.ToLower() == countryCode.ToLower());

    return result.Id
}
```

If I run the application it works fine with "ToLower()", when I run the test result is null but when I remove "ToLower()" it works.

ToLower() not working in Mocks? Or what am I missing?

Comment: In the setup section you only setup the return value for that exact parameter you are using in the setup call. In your GetCountryIdAsync you are using a different parameter, for that parameter the method wasn't set up, so it returns null.

Comment: Which mock library are you using?  The issue seems to be the `x => x.Code == "BE"` that is telling the mock to setup when it sees that function that does not include any `ToLower` calls.  Maybe use `It.IsAny<Func<Country, bool>>()` instead (if you're using Moq)?

Comment: @fbede Oh dear you are right, now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @juharr I tried that already but I get a "cannot convert from 'System.Func<....' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<...'

Comment: In that case you need `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Country, bool>>>()`